# Concept for using statement inside class

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I have a class like this:

```
struct FooImpl {
public:
  using Bar = int;
};
```

I would like to declare that `FooImpl::Bar` is an `int` through a concept.

This does the job:

```
template<typename Foo>
concept FooConcept = requires(Foo foo) {
  { std::vector<typename Foo::Bar>() } -> std::same_as<std::vector<int>>;
};
 
static_assert(FooConcept<FooImpl>);
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this? I tried:

```
  { (typename Foo::Bar)() } -> std::same_as<int>;
```

But the compiler does not seem happy with this.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep: That’s not most-vexing, since a *typename-specifier* can’t be a declarator.  It’s just that you can’t C-style-cast parentheses containing other than 1 expression.

Comment: @DavisHerring You are right, edited my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the reason `{ (typename Foo::Bar)() } -> std::same_as<int>;` doesn't work is because <del>of [*most vexing parse*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)</del> typename-specifier can’t be a declarator, and cannot be used within a C-styly-cast parentheses.* To make it work, you should use a brace init instead:

```cpp
template<typename Foo>
concept FooConcept = requires(Foo foo) {
    { typename Foo::Bar{} } -> std::same_as<int>;
};
```

<sup>* Corrected by ***@DavisHerring*** from the comment</sup>

---

Second, if the only constraint you have is to make sure a certain nested type is the same as another, you can simply use [`std::same_as`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/same_as):

```cpp
template<typename Foo>
concept FooConcept = std::same_as<typename Foo::Bar, int>;
```

---

Last, some terminologies:

> I would like to declare that `FooImpl::Bar` is an `int` through a concept.

Declaring `FooImpl::Bar` is an `int` was already done by the using statement(`using Bar = int`). What you probably meant is:

- You want to declare a concept for a type `T` that requires `T::Bar` to be an `int`.

Or:

- You want to constraint a type `T` that `T::Bar` is an `int` through a concept.

Comment: Thanks, the brace init is what I was looking for. I indeed have other constraints in my actual use case, which is why I sought a solution using `requires`.

Comment: Although my terminology is admittedly sloppy, your suggested improvement references `Foo` before declaring it.

Comment: @dshin Wasn't `Foo` a template typename in your code? It would be the same as substituting `Foo` with `T`

Comment: Yes, my point is simply that the sentence that you proposed to replace occurs *before* the template typename `Foo` is introduced.

Comment: @dshin Edited my answer to use *'`Foo`'* -> *'a type `T`'* to better imply the context

Comment: Sure, that works. On the other hand, those replacement sentences are devoid of any reference to `FooImpl`. This sort of puts the `FooImpl` code-snippet on an island, with the only subsequent reference to it in the remainder of the answer coming in the form of the `static_assert` statement. This in turn seems to call for putting your sentence at the beginning, then the `Foo` concept next, followed by `FooImpl`. Is this a better way to write the question?

Comment: @dshin I agree that this puts the `FooImpl` code-snippet on an island. However, I believe the question was about how to write the concept/require statement, right? Remember that concepts are just functions for metaprogramming, the require statement is the definition of it, and `FooImpl` in your case is the argument passed to that metaprogramming function. So `FooImpl` is really the object not the subject in this question. Someone should deduce a similar answer even without the definition of `FooImpl`.

Comment: @dshin In the same sense that if I was to ask how to write a `bool func(int n)`, the value `i` that I would like to pass to the function is likely not important. What is important is what `func` does, and having `i` with different values shouldn't change the way `func` was defined.